# What is the "correct" canvas in PyQt FigureCanvas?

Tags: canvas, matplotlib, pyqt4

### What am I trying to do?

I am trying to build a PyQt gui that receives a matplotlib figure instance from another function and updates the view after some user input.

### What have I done and what does not work?

I created a custom `FigureCanvas` class which is itself attached to a `QSplitter`. There are two (related) questions that leave me puzzled:

- What is the correct canvas of the `FigureCanvas` class to attach the matplotlib figure to?
- How can I correctly update the window?

Here the code:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

class dataWidget(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, data, title='Title', ax_aspect='auto', parent=None):

        self.fig  = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=120)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.set_aspect(ax_aspect)

        self.title  = self.fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')

        super(dataWidget, self).__init__(self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        self.data     = data
        self.dataType = None

    def plotQuadTree(self, scaleMin=None, scaleMax=None):
        # figQT is a matplotlib figure instance generated
        # by figQT = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5)) in getQTimage()
        figQT, ax, rectangles, sm = self.data.getQTimage(scaleMin, scaleMax)
        print 'updating figure'
        self.fig = figQT
        self.draw()
        self.update()
```

After the class is initialised, its function `plotQuadTree` is called to retrieve and plot the new figure.

### More details on what is going on

#### Question 1: What is the correct canvas of the `FigureCanvas` class to attach the matplotlib figure to?

With the code above an empty figure is shown, i.e. the new figure (coming from `plotQuadTree`) is not replacing the figure generated during `__init__`().

To my surprise I can make the new figure visible by replacing a single line in `plotQuadTree`, i.e. changing

```
        self.fig = figQT
```

to

```
        self.figure = figQT
```

From this I now assume that `FigureCanvas` already has a figure instance that is automatically generated when calling `super(dataWidget, self).__init__(self.fig)`. What I do not understand however is why my `self.fig` instance is not replacing the automatically generated one properly? I would very much appreciate if someone could shed some light on this.

#### Question 2: How can I correctly update the window?

After "hacking" my `FigureCanvas` class as described in Question 1 I can now make the figure visible. After some user input which calls `plotQuadTree` again, the window is not properly updated. Not properly updated means that the new figure is not centred and the old figure remains visible underneath the new figure. However, upon resizing the gui window the new figure is immediately drawn perfectly. How can I force the update within the `plotQuadTree` function call?

Thanks!

Comment: You are never associating the canvas with the figure.

Comment: See the examples here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/index.html

Comment: which is what you are doing by changing to `self.figure`. You are accidentally touching the internal of the `Canvas` class.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/tacaswell/leidenfrost/blob/master/leidenfrost/gui/reader_gui.py for a more complete (but correspondingly more confusing) example.

Comment: I was suspecting that I am touching the internals of the `Canvas` class by changing to `self.figure`. Doesn't `super(dataWidget, self).__init__(self.fig)` attaches self.fig to the canvas?

Comment: How can I associate the canvas with the figure? I tried with the examples @tcaswell provided but I can't get it to work for my problem. After calling `plotQuadTree` I always end up with an empty figure.
Could it be a problem to change the `self.fig` reference in `plotQuadTree` by `self.fig = figQT`?